# Allowing Overflow X

Tags: css, overflow

my code is as follows:

```
#under {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #D4D4D4;
    border: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 4px 0px #000000;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 4px 0px #000000;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 4px 0px #000000;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#under ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#under ul li {
    min-width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #999;
    display: block;
}
```

Basically, I have the #under div with li elements inside of it. I want them to 'overflow' the container so that it can scroll on the X-axis, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do this!

It will make the li elements display under each other.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

EDIT: Live Example https://babblebox.me/mobile/

Comment: *"I want them to 'overflow' the container so that it can scroll on the X-axis, but I cannot for the life of me figure out why."* - You can't figure out why you want to do that? ;)

Comment: Anyway, I think you missed out a bit of your sentence. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Which browser are you using? This property does not work in IE8 and earlier.

Comment: Aha, let me rephrase that, "I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do this" - And my browser is Chrome 15

Comment: @Joel Etherton: It works in IE5+, albeit with a few quirks.

Comment: @BoltClock: Very well, this property does not work as intended "out of the box" in IE versions below 9. A hack will be necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

they are still under because it's floating, and because width:100% it's resizing to available size of screen not div.

Basically i think you should add to ul some width

i mean:

```
#under ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 8000px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always scroll the immediate children of an element. You can either make a really wide `<ul>` as Kokers said or, as I would do it, make apply the scrolling styling on the `<ul>`.

```css
#under {                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #D4D4D4;
    border: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 4px 0px #000000;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 4px 0px #000000;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 4px 0px #000000;

}   
#under ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
}   
#under ul li {
    min-width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    background-color: #999;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

*Note: I changed in `float: left; display: block` to `display: inline-block` in `#under ul li`

here you can see it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/rvt5N/

Answer (score 0):

you have make width of #under to less than it is,
than your overflow works and give width in pixel...

Answer (score -1):

try `overflow: auto;` in `#under` ?

Comment: ahhh ignore my answer then. I'll test stuff before I answer next time